# How to decrement the amount of tries in a Hangman game only when guessed incorrectly?

Tags: java

I was working on a Hangman game in Java with guidance of Youtube and the number of tries decrements even when the player guesses the word correctly. What should I add to my code to decrement the number of tries only when the player guesses incorrectly?

I have tried use a boolean letterIsGuessed, but I can't put it in a loop where it checks the correct ones, because it will also check where the letter isn't and still put out a false value.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package project_hangman;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author NoSwear
 */
public class Project_Hangman {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    String[] guesses = {"yoko", "michael", "slovakia", "shimura ken", "yuuta", "sunshine", "shiritori", "yokohama", "kyoto", "programming", "smartphone", "shinzo abe", "katakana", "kaomoji", "iron man", "shogi", "anime", "kendo", "kyudo", "kenjutsu"};

    boolean Playing = true;     // Separates the game over and the game itself 

    while (Playing) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Hangman game!");
        System.out.println("Developed by NoSwear");

        char[] randomWordGuess = guesses[random.nextInt(guesses.length)].toCharArray();     // Takes a random position of the word in the "guesses" field and grabs it, turns them into char
        int amountOfGuesses = 10;
        char[] playerGuess = new char[amountOfGuesses];

        for (int i = 0; i < playerGuess.length; i++) {
            playerGuess[i] = '_';
        }

        boolean wordIsGuessed = false;      // Whole word guessed
        int tries = 0;      // Goes into println, informs the player about the amount of guesses he/she has made

        while (!wordIsGuessed && tries != amountOfGuesses) {
            System.out.println("Current guesses : ");
            printArray(playerGuess);
            System.out.printf("You have %d tries left.\n", amountOfGuesses - tries);    // See : String conversion
            System.out.println("Enter a single character");
            char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);      // Takes only the first letter in the whole sentence the user will input


            if (input == '-') {
                Playing = false;
                wordIsGuessed = true;
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < randomWordGuess.length; i++) {
                    if (randomWordGuess[i] == input) {
                        playerGuess[i] = input;
                    } 
                }

                tries++;


                if (isTheWordGuessed(playerGuess)) {
                    wordIsGuessed = true;
                    System.out.println("Congratulations, you won the game!");
                }
            }               
        } 
        if (!wordIsGuessed) System.out.println("You ran out of guesses :(");
        System.out.println("Do you want to play another game? (yes/no)");
        String anotherGame = scanner.nextLine();
        if (anotherGame.equals("no")) Playing = false;
    }
    System.out.println("Game over");

}

public static void printArray(char[] array) {       // Prints the current state of the word guess
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isTheWordGuessed(char[] array) {      // Checks if all empty spaces are filled
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == '_') return false;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

After a correct letter is guessed :

(example)
Expected result =

> Current guesses :
>   _ _ _ _ a _ a _
>   You have 10 tries left.
>   Enter a single character

Actual result =

> Current guesses :
>   _ _ _ _ a _ a _
>   You have 9 tries left.
>   Enter a single character

Comment: Specify the input this program should take and output this program should print properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your code

```
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < randomWordGuess.length; i++) {
                if (randomWordGuess[i] == input) {
                    playerGuess[i] = input;
                } 
            }

            tries++;
```

You need to add a condition to `tries` **but** you increment `tries` in every iteration.

declare `boolean isMatch=false;` and use this variable inside the if statement to know that your control had a **positive match**

```
        } else {
            isMatch = false;//-------------------------------------------
            for (int i = 0; i < randomWordGuess.length; i++) {
                if (randomWordGuess[i] == input) {
                    isMatch=true;//--------------------------------------
                    playerGuess[i] = input;
                } 
            }
            if(!isMatch)//------------------------------------------------
                tries++;
```

Also make sure you are assigning `isMatch` with a `false` value after or before every iteration of the main loop.

Comment: You now only counts successful answers. The opposite of what OP wants.

Comment: @Tom Oh , my bad. Confusing play with variables here, in general one would think of decrementing the `numberOfChances` in such game.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I sort of tried what here is, but it didn't work, so I changed it a bit and now it works perfectly! Thank you

Comment: @NoSwearsk plesae share what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember when a character match was found in your loop:

```
boolean foundACharacter = false;
for (int i = 0; i < randomWordGuess.length; i++) {
    if (randomWordGuess[i] == input) {
        playerGuess[i] = input;
        foundACharacter = true;
    } 
}
```

Then only increment `tries` if there was no match:

```
if (!foundACharacter)
    tries++;
```